# I want to change data table button name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, datatable

I have `excel` button of data table and I want to change name of that button.
I am trying like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loading_sheet_table').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'excel',
        name: 'export to excel'
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

But name not change and I want to add icon after name.

```
<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: try with `text: 'export to excel'`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen how add icon after name

Comment: try  $("'#loading_sheet_table :button").append('<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>')

Comment: something like `text: 'export to excel<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>'`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to get the desired thing

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loading_sheet_table').DataTable({
    "paging": false,
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'excel',
        text: 'Export to excel',
        className: 'btn btn-default btn-xs'
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

I hope you can style your icon using the class.